# Difference between Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() and typeof(program).Assembly

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the difference between `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` and `typeof(program).Assembly`?

Comment: Well, they'll give different answers if `program` doesn't belong to the executing assembly... (For example, if you call it from a class library.) Did you read the documentation for `GetExecutingAssembly`? It's not really clear what's confusing you.

Comment: It would make more sense if your question contained more information about what you want to do. As it stands you're sort of asking "what's the difference between oranges and apples?"

Answer (score 42):

Assuming `program` is in the executing assembly, they should both return the same value.  However, `typeof(program).Assembly` should have better performance, since `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` does a stack walk.  In a micro benchmark on my machine, the former took about 20ns, while the latter was 30x slower at about 600ns.

If you control all the code I think you should always use `typeof(program).Assembly`.  If you provided source code that other people could build into their assemblies, you would need to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Comment: Do you know if there is any risk the method calling `GetExecutingAssembly` will be inlined and an unexpected assembly returned? Like if a derived class in AssemblyB calls an instance method inherited from the base class in AssemblyA, and that method is a one-liner to `GetExecutingAssembly`, can we be sure AssemblyA is returned?

Comment: I am interested to know how you did the micro benchmark!

Answer (score 18):

Calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` will return the assembly containing the method that is calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Calling for example `typeof(string).Assembly` will return **mscorlib.dll** because it contains the type `String`.
On the other hand if you have a project called **MyProject** and somewhere in this project you call `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` it will return the Assembly instance representing **MyProject.dll**

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

**Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly():**
Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.
The following example gets the assembly of the currently running code.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
// Instantiate a target object.
Int32 Integer1 = new Int32();
Type Type1;
// Set the Type instance to the target class type.
Type1 = Integer1.GetType();
// Instantiate an Assembly class to the assembly housing the Integer type.  
SampleAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(Integer1.GetType());
// Display the name of the assembly currently executing
Console.WriteLine("GetExecutingAssembly=" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
```

**typeOf():**
It is mainly use in reflection.
The typeof operator is used to obtain the System.Type object for a type. A typeof expression takes the form:
To obtain the run-time type of an expression, you can use the .NET Framework method GetType.

```
Example
// cs_operator_typeof.cs
// Using typeof operator
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MyClass 
{
   public int intI;
   public void MyMeth() 
   {
   }

   public static void Main() 
   {
      Type t = typeof(MyClass);

      // alternatively, you could use
      // MyClass t1 = new MyClass();
      // Type t = t1.GetType();

      MethodInfo[] x = t.GetMethods();
      foreach (MethodInfo xtemp in x) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine(xtemp.ToString());
      }

      Console.WriteLine();

      MemberInfo[] x2 = t.GetMembers();
      foreach (MemberInfo xtemp2 in x2) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine(xtemp2.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Output

```
Int32 GetHashCode()
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
System.String ToString()
Void MyMeth()
Void Main()
System.Type GetType()

Int32 intI
Int32 GetHashCode()
Boolean Equals(System.Object)
System.String ToString()
Void MyMeth()
Void Main()
System.Type GetType()
Void .ctor()
```

Comment: I see that the first code sample you use comes directly from the documentation on MSDN, but I still think it is a bad and poorly written example.

Answer (score 2):

Following code explains the differences.

```
//string class is defined by .NET framework
var a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(string));
//a = FullName = "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

Since string is defined in mscorlib assembly its full name is returned. So the assembly name will be returned where the type is defined. If I pass my class where I am executing this code,

```
//Program is the class where this code is being executed
var aa = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)); 
//aa = FullName = "Obj_2_5_Using_Reflection, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

var b = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
//b = FullName = "Obj_2_5_Using_Reflection, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```